# Rollback Groovy Transaction on checked exception

Tags: groovy, transactions

I am just upgrading Groovy versions from 1.76 to 2.1 on a project, and I have a unit test as follows:

```
try{
    sql.withTransaction{
        sql.execute("Update table set name='tested' where id = 1")
        throw new Exception()
    }
}
catch(ignore){}

//Assert that name has been rolled back from update to 'tested'
```

Previously in 1.76 this was working correctly - the thrown exception caused the transaction to roll back and all was ok. However, this is not the case in 2.1 - and I have seen that if I change my exception to throw a `RuntimeException` then it is rolled back correctly.

My assumption is that Groovy no longer rolls back my transactions for checked exceptions - is this something that can be configured? Can I make it rollback on all transactions rather than having to go back and update all my code to explicitly rollback when catching exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throw new SQLException()` should rollback the transaction.

`SQLException`, `RuntimeException` and `Error` is caught inside `withTransaction` and rethrown as `SQLException` and transaction rolled back eventually. @Excerpts from groovy source.

To override the functionality to throw SQLException for all tests, you can mock it in setUp as

```
Sql.metaClass.withTransaction = {Closure clos ->
   throw new SQLException()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot of the code is actually working on the assumption that if an exception is thrown whilst working in a transaction thenearlier work is rolled back, so not just a case of changing the tests unfortunately. Was hoping I could configure the transactions to rollback on any exception.

Comment: In the end I handled the case for checked exceptions explicitly - but this answer is correct in the details of Groovy's implementation, so will accept it.

Comment: @rhinds I would love to know how you handled it. I was thinking of showing you some options.